# How do I fix overlapping Git Pull Requests?

Tags: git

I made changes to three files `a, b, & c`

I renamed the `master` branch to `newWorkBranch` and `git add commit and push` my work. I wanted to make some changes so the branch has not been merged on Github

Afterwards I made changes to file `c` for unrelated work and created a new `otherBranch`. When I `git add commit and push` files, all the work including the work from `newWorkBranch` is showing up as part of `otherBranch`

I need a way to:

1. Disassociate `newWorkBranch` work from `otherBranch` including lines of code in file `c`
2. Make sure I can keep making changes to branch `newWorkBranch` without further change

Comment: Will you please show a diagram of the current state of your local repository?

Comment: Did you rename `master` in your local repository or did you also rename it on GitHub? In general, you should create new branches rather than renaming existing ones.

Comment: "Disassociate newWorkBranch work from otherBranch" How did they get associated in the first place? Were you on `newWorkBranch` when you created `otherBranch`? — And why did you rename `master`? It would help if you would show (in your question) the output of `git log --oneline --graph --decorate --all`

Comment: On a side note, sometimes "overlapping pull requests" are exactly what you have to do when one fix depends on another. In such a case, you have to communicate with the reviewer which PR needs to be reviewed and merged first.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I id rename `master` on my local repository on my computer. I've learned my lesson on renaming but need help fixing the existing issue. Pull requests only have one file in common. The second pull request changes to a part of file `c` that do not overlap

Comment: @matt Yes, I was on `newWorkBranch` when I created `otherBranch`
The following is a snippet of the result after I ran your command:
`(origin/otherBranch otherBranch) Cleaner otherBranch()`
`(HEAD -> newWorkBranch, origin/newWorkBranch)`

Comment: Show it _in your question_ as I said before. And format it.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the requested information. Be sure to show the first full page of output from the `git log` command.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you created `otherBranch` on top of `newWorkBranch`. To fix them so that they are independent of each other, you can use `git rebase`:

```
git checkout otherBranch
git rebase --onto origin/master newWorkBranch
```

This will effectively move all of the commits that you made on `otherBranch` which aren't on `newWorkBranch` so that they are on top of `master`.